# Air-Adb: Error "Cannot run program "bash.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: android

I use Android Studio on Windows 10 with an AMD Processor.

I want to connect my phone over android so I installed the Air-Adb plugin.

When I click the menu Tools > Enable wifi over ADB, I got this popup error message (also see the screenshot).

> Air-Adb: Something went wrong (Cannot run program bash.exe; CreateProcess error = 2, The system cannot find the file specified)

Has anyone else had this experience, or know how to fix it?

**Screenshot: refer yellow marked area bottom-right of screen**

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to run your apps over wifi, to do that you need plugin 
so go to **File --> Settings --> Plugins** then search **ADB WiFi connect** download it and restart your Android studio, then you will get a new icon in your top bar click it and connect your phone to computer via USB cable, USB cable is only for the first time.

> Note: your computer and your android phone they must have connected
>   the same network

[image: This is the plugin]

[image]

Comment: Thank You for you answer. Why some one - vote this question.